# Formatting The Error Validation in HTML

Tags: html

I am trying to format the text from the error validation JavaScript below:

```
<script>
function validateForm()
{
    var x=document.forms["myForm"]["firstName"].value;
    if (x==null || x=="")
    {
        document.getElementById('usernameError').innerHTML = "Invalid First Name";
        return false;
    }
}
</script>
```

The JavaScript works as intended, but I need to format the text as it appears on the page. The following is the username field:

```
<fieldset class='step'>
<legend>Personal Information</legend>
<p>
    <label for="firstName">First Name: </label>
    <input type="text" name="firstName"/>
    <div id="usernameError"></div>
</p>
</fieldset>
```

As you can probably imaging, the JavaScript appends/inserts the text "Invalid first name", if the field is empty, however, I need it to be red (as it is an error) and indented to the right. How do I achieve that?

Answer (score 2):

Add this in css:-

```
#usernameError{
color: red;
font-style: italic;
}
```

Comment: @user2948897 further to this question.. here is a fiddle that you can use to tweak things http://jsfiddle.net/gnY8b/1/ as you did ask to have this indented

Comment: I did add that to the CSS, however, it is not changing to red, but it is italized!